# attribute Android: name is not allowed here

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA, i have a problem why when i copy project folder to another always result like this? have attribute Android: name is not allowed here even if i just copy old project to new project with 100% same as source but different like this. how to fix it?
[image]

[image]